# Why does TS let me await a string?

Tags: typescript

This code (using promisified `fs`) has parentheses obviously wrong:

```
    const jsonSource = await fs.readFile(planFilePath).toString();
```

The intention was:

```
    const jsonSource = (await fs.readFile(planFilePath)).toString();
```

And the question is: why does the wrong version even compile? The wrong version stringifies the promise to `"[object Promise]"`, and then the `await` operator applies to that string. TS knows that the `toString()` method of a `Promise<string>` object returns a string. TS also knows that you can't await a string, only a promise. So why does this compile?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This compiles because nearly every value can be awaited, try running the example below in your browser.

```
(async function() {
  console.log(await Promise.resolve(console.log('')));
  const test = 'testing';
  console.log(await test);
  console.log(await 33);
}());
```

the docs state this behaviour:

> If the value is not a Promise, it converts the value to a resolved Promise, and waits for it.

docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await

Comment: Aaah. So this isn't one of those cases where static type checking saves us cumulative years of debugging. Unless there are lint tools that will catch this particular scenario (`await somethingThatReturnsPromise().toString()`) because this is probably incorrect 99% of the time.